# An unknown mathematical sign?

Tags: math-mode

### Problem

When I am reading a paper, there is a definition
[image]

But I do not know what is the set where 
[image]
resides in and how do I get it.

More generally, if you see a mathematical sign you do not know, what is the most straight way to get it when you want to use the same sign.

### What I Have Done

By using Mathpix, a tool that transform image to tex command, it parses that set as 
[image]
with high probability. But this **doe not** make sense from the context of the paper.

A side comment, I am new to this forum, but isn't it weird I could not directly type formulas just as other StackExchange sites (like Maths StackExchange, MathOverfolw and Cross-Validated)?

Thank you.

Comment: `\mathcal{E}` with `eulervm` package loaded?

Comment: A good place to start is [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: @Manuel Change E to J and I think you've got the answer.

Comment: A good reference for all the script, blackboard, calligraphic and Fraktur letters is [the documentation for `mathalfa`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalfa/doc/mathalfa.pdf), which includes a comprehensive set of font samples for legacy fonts, or [this list of symbols defined by `unicode-math`](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) for Unicode fonts.

Comment: Finally, you might find the symbol on [The Comprehensive TeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s the J from Euler Script.  Compare:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Also eufrak if needed.

\begin{document}
\( \mu_j (h) = \mathbb{E}
  \left[ g_j \big(X, A, Y, h(X)\big) \middle| \mathcal{E}_j \right]
  \text{ for } j \in \mathcal{J}
 \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

Or in the modern toolchain, with `unicode-math` and either XeTeX or LuaTeX:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range = {cal, bfcal, frak, bffrak}]{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range = {bb, bbit}]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
\( \mu_j (h) = \mathbb{E}
  \left[ g_j \big(X, A, Y, h(X)\big) \middle| \mathcal{E}_j \right]
  \text{ for \(j \in \mathcal{J}\).}
 \)
\end{document}
```

[image: unicode-math font sample]

This doesn’t exactly duplicate the spacing of your scan, but it’s enough to demonstrate that the glyphs are the same.